# Failing to Compile InferenceEngine Openvino using MVN operation

Tags: machine-translation, openvino

I'm in progress converting the [MBART](https://huggingface.co/facebook/mbart-large-50-many-to-many-mmt) model from HuggingFace Transformer to the OpenVino IF format and I've "successfully" brokendown the original pytorch model graph into 3 seperate ONNX models. I then used the `mo.py` to convert the onnx model to the IF format model to use the inference engine in openvino for "MYRIAD" Neural Compute Stick 2 . Its essentially two encoders and one decoder. I'm trying to test the first encoder model to see if a simple inference engine load works.

I'm geting the following error:

```
[ INFO ] Loading Inference Engine
[ INFO ] Loading network:
[ INFO ]     c:\protoc\models\translator\encoder\model.xml
[ INFO ] Device info:
[ INFO ]         MYRIAD
[ INFO ]         MKLDNNPlugin version ......... 2.1
[ INFO ]         Build ........... 2021.3.0-2774-d6ebaa2cd8e-refs/pull/4731/head
[ INFO ] Inputs number: 2
[ INFO ]     Input name: attention_mask
[ INFO ]     Input shape: [1, 92]
....

RuntimeError: Failed to compile layer "Div_25": Unsupported combination of indices in layer "Div_25". Only accross channel and full batch supported.
```

I check the `Div_25` layer and it looks like:

```xml
<layer id="30" name="Div_25" type="MVN" version="opset6">
            <data eps="9.999999747378752e-06" eps_mode="inside_sqrt" normalize_variance="true"/>
            <input>
                <port id="0">
                    <dim>1</dim>
                    <dim>92</dim>
                    <dim>1024</dim>
                </port>
                <port id="1">
                    <dim>1</dim>
                </port>
            </input>
            <output>
                <port id="2" precision="FP32" names="231">
                    <dim>1</dim>
                    <dim>92</dim>
                    <dim>1024</dim>
                </port>
            </output>
        </layer>
```

Reading the [MVN](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_ops_normalization_MVN_6.html) documentation, and tried putting various values for `port id="1"` under dim with not luck. I unfortunately don't fully understand what its warning me about to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the ONNX model that you use with the Div_25 layer is not yet supported by OpenVINO. You may refer to these documents on the [Supported Framework layer](http://It%20seems%20that%20the%20ONNX%20model%20that%20you%20are%20using%20with%20the%20Div_25%20layer%20is%20not%20yet%20supported%20by%20OpenVINO.%20You%20may%20refer%20to%20these%20documents%20on%20the%20Supported%20Framework%20layer.).

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the [MVN-1](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/openvino_docs_ops_normalization_MVN_1.html) operation as it would cater to the across channels flag. We suggest you use OpenVINO 2021.4, which has been released recently.